# How to convert comma separated string enclosed in quotes, with spaces to a list with separate elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string separated with comma (,) and enclosed in single quotes ('') to a list , and the list must have it as separate elements. Following is the string

```
String_tobe_Tested = " 'hello', 'Ruper's', 'how am i and', 'are','you'"
```

If you look at the string closely then you will notice that there is space between the word and the start or comma like `, 'Ruper's'` .

So when I convert this to a list it gives the length as 2 in place of 5 . 2 because there is no space in the last word 'you'.

I would like to convert this to a list with each element properly that is if there is , between the sentence inside '' like `'how are you doing,and how am I'` it must be separated as it is, that is 'how are you doing,and how am I' should be a single element . Following is my code.

```
 String_tobe_Tested = String_tobe_Tested.strip('"')
#String_tobe_Tested = eval(String_tobe_Tested)
String_tobe_Tested = String_tobe_Tested.split("','")
print(len(String_tobe_Tested))
```

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks :)

**Edit:**
String_tobe_Tested = "'500Mbps', 'Air Force', 'Falcon', 'Wyler's', 'the National Security Space Launch', 'the United Launch Alliance', 'Windows', 'Europeanized', 'Samsung', 'the University of Bremen', 'S8+', 'The International Astronautical Federation', 'NASA', 'Boeing', 'ABC', 'BFR', 'Microsoft', 'Musk', 'the National Defense Authorization Act', 'Facebook', 'Baseline Commitment', 'Senate', 'Business Insider', 'VR', 'Bots', 'SLS', 'Falcon Heavy', 'Office of Inspector General', 'the Air Force', 'The U.S. Air Force', 'FCC', 'the Senate Commerce, Science and Transportation Committee', 'Google', 'Virgin Orbit', 'IAC', 'EELV', 'Symantec', 'the Agency Baseline Commitment', 'Neuralink', 'Aerojet Rocketdyne', 'Congress', 'Lockheed Martin', 'Tesla', 'Northrop', 'Obama', 'Commercial Crew Program', 'SpaceX', 'Trump', 'the International Astronautical Congress', 'The Department of Defense', 'Oculus', 'OIG', 'Arianespace', 'ULA', 'Oculus Rift', 'the Armed Forces', 'Lockheed', 'Galaxy S8', 'Facebook Stories', 'University of Bremen', 'OneWeb', 'House', 'Tencent', 'Blue Origin', 'Elon Muskâ\x80\x99s'"

**See this list**

prev_keywords = ['Boeing', 'the National Security Space Launch', 'Facebook Stories', 'BFR', 'Europeanized', 'Elon Muskâ\x80\x99s', 'Facebook', 'VR', 'Blue Origin', 'Trump', 'the Air Force', 'NASA', 'Virgin Orbit', 'OIG', 'Air Force', 'Commercial Crew Program', 'Samsung', 'the Agency Baseline Commitment', 'OneWeb', 'Falcon Heavy',
                  'Neuralink', 'SpaceX', 'the United Launch Alliance', 'Microsoft', 'FCC', 'ULA', 'Lockheed', 'Musk', 'Google', 'Lockheed Martin',
                 'Symantec', '500Mbps', 'Office of Inspector General', 'S8+', 'Tencent', 'Business Insider', 'Falcon', 'The Department of Defense',
                 'Obama', 'the Senate Commerce', 'Science and Transportation Committee', 'Wyler', 'the University of Bremen', 'Bots',
                 'Tesla', 'Galaxy S8', 'the International Astronautical Congress', 'The U.S. Air Force', 'Oculus', 'University of Bremen',
                 'Senate', 'the Armed Forces', 'Congress', 'Arianespace', 'Oculus Rift', 'Aerojet Rocketdyne', 'IAC',
                 'Baseline Commitment', 'The International Astronautical Federation',
                  'the National Defense Authorization Act', 'Northrop', 'SLS', 'ABC', 'House']

```
 myList = list(set(String_tobe_tested) - set(prev_keywords))

    len(myList)
```

Should be zero if there is no different in the lists.

Comment: You are just over complicating things. Try this `len(String_tobe_Tested.split(','))` gives 5

Comment: `[i.strip(" '") for i in String_tobe_Tested.split(',')]` gives `['hello', "Ruper's", 'how am i and', 'are', 'you']` length of this list is 5.

Comment: @Ch3steR The problem with this approach is if there is a , inside the element like 'how, am, i and' then it treats how and am as separate elements, which I don't want, split must be according to ' ' and not comma, also the case lies where there is apostrophe in a sentence.

Comment: @snakecharmerb okay let me do it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Hi I have edited my question. I am getting it from database and hence I am getting those spaces.

Comment: @Pritish you have to trim those out. if they are present using some regex or something.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Wyler is obvious because in original string there is no apostrophe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
import re

String_tobe_Tested = " 'hello', 'Ruper's', 'how am i and', 'are','you'"
String_tobe_Tested = String_tobe_Tested.lstrip(' ')
String_tobe_Tested = String_tobe_Tested[1:-1]
print(String_tobe_Tested)
String_tobe_Tested = String_tobe_Tested.strip('"')
#String_tobe_Tested = eval(String_tobe_Tested)
#String_tobe_Tested = String_tobe_Tested.split("','")
String_tobe_Tested = re.compile("','|', '").split(String_tobe_Tested)
print(String_tobe_Tested)
print(len(String_tobe_Tested))
```

Comment: Great, it is working , let me try it for few more different type of strings and I will accept this answer, btw can you please explain '|' in re ? I am quite new in python

Comment: Well, here I am using regular expression here. imported the re package.
If you dig into the regular expression the `|` stands for OR operator. So basically it splits by either `'|'` or `', '`. You can add more ORs if you want.

Comment: Please see my edited question, I have added a new string, it is treating few words differently, for example it is taking " '500Mbps" , see the first word , so there is one ' before 500 enclosed in " "

Comment: Use something like this String_tobe_Tested = String_tobe_Tested[2:-1]

Comment: @Pritish to strip our the unnecessary characters from start and end.

Comment: String_tobe_Tested[2:-1] did you mean String_tobe_Tested[1:-1] ?? 2 is taking out the word after " as well. Can't I just loop through it and remove the spaces between , and "word"

Comment: @Pritish In your first example it started like this " 'hello',
But in your origional example that you are getting from DB has no leading space. SO you may have to use [1:-1]

Comment: Yes that is the problem , that every string my appear differently, can't I have a check that if there is space then 2 else 1 ?

Comment: @Pritish yes you can check that. Let me edit my answer

Comment: [1:-1] worked for the first string as well, don't know even after adding two spaces like "  'hello'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211462/discussion-between-ayus-mohanty-and-pritish).